# Right way of using react-hook-form with typescript and material-ui for showing error message

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form with typescript and material-ui. I wanted to pass error message as a `helperText` to `TextField`. I have tried to do so using 
`helperText={errors.email?.message}`
but typescript complains about this assignment.

```
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'NestDataObject<FormData>'.ts(2339)
```

I don't want to disable this rule from my .eslintrc file, because it may ignore other similar issues in my application, which may be desired at some places.
What is the right way of assigning error message of react-hook-form as a helperText to material-ui components?

codesandbox link 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-form-hook-yi669

Comment: You don't have email defined in your `FormData` type.

Comment: Thats right, but what's the appropriate way of defining it? FormData coming from `react-hook-form` package.

Comment: Oh. Thanks @HunterMcMillen for hint. It's working now. Posting an answer.

Comment: No you defined it on line 5 of app.tsx: `type FormData = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};
`

Comment: Yes. updated my own sandbox, but then reverted and forked another one for answer. Thanks for help @HunterMcMillen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to define a datatype for form data and pass it to 'useForm'.

```
type FormData = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm<FormData>();
```

Updated sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-form-hook-answer-8cxc1

Comment: Thank you sir, after several hours without a solution, this works perfectly!

Comment: Hi @Mahesh,  I used the above code but  the error I get is  " Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'UseFormReturn<FormData>'.ts(2339) "